# Apache couchdb for Dummies Adding datebase property to angularjs/javascript file

Tags: javascript, database, angularjs, apache, couchdb

I'm totally new in datebases.
I was wonder if somebody could explain my how should I use this Apache couchDB.
How to add my database to Javascript file.
How to run commends in cmd form javascript file to nagivate ( add/delete) thru json file.

If it possible to explain it as easy as it is possible :)

Comment: You're asking us to reproduce huge chunks of CouchBD's documentation. If you are a beginner, you should start reading the docs here: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ AND here: http://guide.couchdb.org/. They are easy to follow and very educative.

Comment: `If it possible to explain it as easy as it is possible :)` - Unfortunately it's not possible...